# Sending data serially in an android phone via USB without connecting to computer

Tags: android, arduino

I want to send data like '0xFF' serially from an android phone without using bluetooth module. I just want to use **USB cable only**. The usb cable will not be connected to the computer, it will be connect to a device with "Zero" intelligence.

Is it possible to do this without rooting the phone?

Can it be done by writing an app?

Comment: There's USB APIs on Android, but it assumes you want to send the data in USB format-  that includes a lot of headers and handshakes on connections.  You could then send down 0xFF serially, but it won't work with a truly dumb endpoint.

Comment: For a truly simple peripheral, one would use a USB-serial converter, just as with a desktop.   Android devices without USB host mode can run the USB in the reverse direction using the ADK APIs with the ADK external processor converting to serial, or for devices too old even for that, the 3rd party microbridge embedded ADB implementation.  In the first, the Android device powers the peripheral, in the later two cases the peripheral has to "at least sort of" charge the Android device.

Answer (score 0):

I would say No, only in the sense only in the sense the USB cable approach is not likely to be worth the work.  Even if you rooted and wrote all the phone side code, a USB interface is still more like a network with device identification, time slicing to share bandwidth, etc.  I would not expect that you would get the controller on the phone side to transmit anything until a proper device was on the other side.

One output you do have that is available and under full control is the audio output.  Sound files can be constructed and sent.  A protocol similar to how an IR remote works is just pulses of sound.  The receiving device would only need to be a smart as typical IR receiver.  These are quite cheap and simple, e.g. if you could output sound at the 38 kHz IR carrier frequency, this would be a solution with replacement of the photodiode with a cable.:

[IR receiver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8554)

There is good reason Square uses the audio port and not the USB port...

[Square](https://squareup.com/)